# Proof of Floquet's theorem in Chicone's book about differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am working through the proof of the following theorem from Chicone's book about ODEs:
[image]

**The follwoing statement causes me some headache:**
From theorem 2.47(see below) I can only deduce that there is a $B$ such that $e^{B}=C$. Where does the $T$ come from in both cases?

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

---

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a $\tilde{B}$ such that $e^{\tilde{B}}=C$, this you agree with, right? So, $e^{T\left(T^{-1}\tilde{B}\right)}=C$ ($T$ is just a scalar). Define $B\equiv T^{-1}\tilde{B}$. So, there is a ${B}$ such that $e^{T{B}}=C$. The author of the book needs the theorem in the form $e^{T{B}}=C$, to prove his own Theorem.

Comment: Oh okay...thanks....makes definetly sense.